# App Name in iTunnesConnect

Tags: ios

I would like to take a name for my application from itunnesconnect. However, the name that I want to take has been taken by someone else. However, if I change default language from English to UK English, that name becomes available. I wonder what if I take that name with default language "UK English". What would be difference ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the name is not identical to one already in the store, you can use it. However, it is very hard to find apps in the store even if you know their name, so you might want to think about having a spelling that is not common. e.g If there is already a game called Color It and you want to name yours Colour It, there is a good chance that people who are searching for it will find the other one instead of yours.

I have a game that I’ve sold for years on CD called Show Me. That name was taken in the app store so I call mine Show Me… They are completely different apps, so my customers don’t buy the wrong one by mistake.

I also have one called Train Talk! that is based on my CD game Train Talk (without the !). Again, they are completely different apps and my customers won’t accidentally buy the wrong one.